# What is an easy way to reduce a boronic acid to borane?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have a selection of boronic acids that I want to reduce to borane forms. Some of the boronic acids in question are phenylboronic acid (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>5</sub>B(OH)<sub>2</sub>), tolylboronic acid (C<sub>7</sub>H<sub>7</sub>B(OH)<sub>2</sub>), and p-phenylenediborinic acid (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>4</sub>(B(OH)<sub>2</sub>)<sub>2</sub>). I want to convert them into phenylborane (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>5</sub>BH<sub>2</sub>), tolylborane (C<sub>7</sub>H<sub>7</sub>BH<sub>2</sub>), and p-phenylenediborane (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>4</sub>(BH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>2</sub>).

I think I can do this by dissolving the boronic acid in ether and adding Lithium Aluminum Hydride (LAH). Giving a reaction that looks something like:

[image: Reduction of Phenylboronic acid]

However, I am afraid that, given how aggressive a reducing agent LAH is I might get something like:

[image]

So I guess I have two questions:

- Will LAH attack the boron-carbon bond shown in the second reaction diagram?
- Can the reduction of the boronic acid be accomplished via a less aggressive reducing agent, perhaps Sodium BoroHydride?

Just a note: I am well aware that the boranes produced will be oxygen sensitive, either converting back to boric acid on exposure to oxygen, or catching fire.

Comment: There are quite a lot of reducing agents out there. $\ce{DIBAL-H}$ is one of them. $\ce{Sn + HCl}$ is yet another. So is $\ce{NaBH4}$. So many out there.

Comment: I know there are a lot out there, but are they strong enough to reduce boronic acids? As I said in one of my questions: Can the reduction be accomplished with something less aggressive than LAH, like NaBH4.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Just because reducing agents exist doesn't mean they will be able to affect a particular transformation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LAH will attack the boron-oxygen bonds without going after the boron-carbon bond, see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ANQtNtt1jcwC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=lialh4+borate+esters&source=bl&ots=RdAyDbjT5n&sig=BEDbLEmBedAIjuavh1SMe1Wn4i4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS94yrpfLTAhUIhlQKHZ2JCKAQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=lialh4%20borate%20esters&f=false) (Eq. Z, p. 142).

But it also deprotonates the hydroxyl groups as a strong base like a Grignard reagent. You need to prevent that.  Convert your acid to an ester (OH -> OR), remove the water and then apply the LAH.

Comment: Upvote for the reference and the useful note, I hadn't thought about what would happen to the hydroxyl group once it was removed. Out of curiosity, if I do not convert to the ester first, will it just require more LAH and leave me with Aluminum oxide and Lithium oxide? Or will something more insidious happen?

Comment: What's insidious is if you deprotonate the hydroxyl groups the boron loses its electrophilicity and you don't get the hydride transfer.  Compare with a Grignard reagent which converts a carboxylate ester to an alcohol but the parent acid just gives a salt.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. As a physicist with a little more chemistry than most physicists under my belt I have gotten mixed up in liquid scintillator development but sometimes that little bit of extra knowledge isn't enough because of how hazy it is.