# I need to reduce the Nitrile group without affecting the boronic acid. How to do that?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction, nitriles, organoboron-compounds

I need to Reduce the Nitrile group (CN) in the (3-cyanophenyl)boronic acid in to a primary amine without disturbing the Boronic acid group.Using LAH can trigger reduction of Boronic group. what are my options?

[image]

Comment: Options : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrile_reduction

Comment: The answer and  comments to this question are relevent https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74580/what-is-an-easy-way-to-reduce-a-boronic-acid-to-borane

Comment: SmI2 looks a possibility  Org. Lett., 2014, 16, 1092-1095.

Comment: Also could protect the boronate, perhaps with MIDA?